# Print data out from foreach

Tags: codeigniter, foreach

I have a list in this way:

```
foreach ($productos as $p) { 
  echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td>' . $p->codigoProducto . '</td>'; 
  echo '<td>' . $p->categoriaNombre . '</td>'; 
  echo '<td>' . $p->marcaNombre . '</td>'; 
  echo '<td>' . $p->detalleProducto . '</td>'; 
  echo '<td>' . $p->precioProducto . '</td>'; 
  echo '</tr>'; 
}
```

I need to print:

> Categoria A
>
> Código | Marca | Detalle | Precio
>   1
>   2
>   3

---

> Categoria B
>
> Código | Marca | Detalle | Precio
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   ...

Just show categoriaNombre and then the products but with foreach I don't know how to show it.

Comment: What are you getting at the moment? what is the structure of $productos ? ( print_r($productos) )

Comment: Please post array

Answer (score 0):

first loop is loop for category header which is in your case,it's Categoria A or Categoria B.make a query for Distinct the category header.this is the query example

```
**Controller for loop**

function loop_item()
{
--Showing the Category --

  $category = $this->db->query("
  SELECT DISTINCT b.id_category,b.category_name name,a.id from tbl_a a
  LEFT JOIN tbl_b b on a.id_category = b.id_category
  where a.id_category !=''")->result_array();

-- End Showing the Category --
-- Loop for item inside category --

foreach($category as $key => $value)
  {
    $category[$key]['items'] = $this->db->query("
    SELECT a.id,a.marca marca,a.detalle detalle,a.precio precio
    FROM tbl_a a
    LEFT JOIN tbl_b b on a.id_category=b.id_category
    where a.id_category=".$value['id_category'])->result_array();
  }
-- End Loop for item inside category --
$d['listcategory'] = $category;
}

**Views**
<?php $i=1;foreach($listcategory as $value) 
{ 
 echo $value['nama']."<br>";
?>
<table>
 <thead>
  <th>Codigo</th>
  <th>Marca</th>
  <th>Detalle</th>
  <th>Precio</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php $number= 1; foreach($value['items'] as $val){ ?>
 <tr> 
  <td><?= $number;?></td>
  <td><?= $val['marca'];?></td>
  <td><?= $val['detalle'];?></td>
  <td><?= $val['precio'];?></td>
 </tr>
<?php $number++; } ?>
</tbody>
```

That is how i did it .because i make the same thing as you did.the one i make is dynamic.it would be easier if the category is only 2 category ,you can set static category by adding new field in database to determine which item it linked to.